# How to make Nautilus notice changes regarding group permissions

Tags: permissions, nautilus, group

If I follow a process [I mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6387/688), I am supposed to log out and then in for the changes to take place. What about Nautilus? I tried to restart it and was still unsuccessful. The only way I have so far found that works is logging out of the desktop and then in again. That's not always convenient of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't grant a new group to a running process.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/how-to-add-write-permissions-for-a-group/11573#11573) You need to log in again to get a process with the changed group memberships.

What you can do is to launch nautilus from a different session but have it display on your existing display, something like

```
ssh localhost "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus &"
```