# How to apply changes of newly added user groups without needing to reboot?

Tags: permissions, users, group

Assume I'm logged in with user `takpar`:

```
takpar@skyspace:/$
```

As root, I've added `takpar` as a member of group `webdev` using:

```
# usermod -a -G webdev takpar
```

But it seems it has not been applied, because for example I can't get into a `webdev`'s directory that has read permission for group:

```
400169 drwxr-x--- 3 webdev webdev 4.0K 2011-08-15 22:34 public_html

takpar@skyspace:/home/webdev/$ cd public_html/
bash: cd: public_html/: Permission denied
```

But after a reboot I have access as I expect. As this kind of group changing is in my routine, is there any way to apply changes without needing a reboot?

**Answer**
It seems there is no way to make the current session know the new group, for example the file manager won't work with new changes. But a re-login will do the job.
The `su` command is also appropriate for temp commands in urrent session.

Comment: You don't need to reboot, only to login again so that the permissions changes become global.

Comment: There is no way to change any _process_ (in particular, login session's) identity while it is running (UID, GID, supplemental groups). Need to start a new session (i.e., log in again).

Comment: what if the created user is a system user?

Comment: See also: [SuperUser: Reload a Linux user's group assignments without logging out](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Local solution: use `su yourself` to login again. In the new session you'll be considered as a member of the group.

---

Man pages for `newgrp` and `sg` might also be of interest to change your current group id (and login into a new group):

- To use `webdev`'s group id (and privileges) in your current shell use:

  ```
   newgrp webdev
  ```
- To start a command with some group id (and keep current privileges in your shell) use:

  ```
   sg webdev -c "command"
  ```

  (`sg` is like `su` but for groups, and it should work without the group password if you are listed as a member of the group in the system's data)

Comment: It asks for a password, and do not accept neither my password neither webdev's one.

Comment: @takpar: I've just checked, and in fact it seems it should work without the (group) password when you are listed as a member of the group in `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`. Are your two files consistent? (check it with `grpck -r`).

Comment: it can work. sg group_name -c "bash"

Comment: I am installing docker using ansible and I am maintaining a socket file in my local machine for 120s, how can I achieve the same with ansible?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - what do you mean by *and login into a new group*?

Answer (score 6):

Rebooting system is an overkill, even logout & login is not necessary if you use `gpasswd`.

You can add `takpar` to `webdev` group using:

```
$ gpasswd -a <user> <group>
```

In your case it would be:
`$ gpasswd -a takpar webdev`

You can check group membership using `getent group {name}` command:

```
$ getent group webdev
webdev:x:1008:webdev,takpar
```

which should be the same as `cat /etc/group | grep webdev`. For completeness here's `id` output from from `takpar` shell session:

```
$ id takpar
uid=1007(takpar) gid=1007(takpar) groups=1007(takpar),1008(webdev)
```

Comment: This solution enables me to continue executing commands after adding user to the group. W/ newgrp command this is not possible e.g. in a bash script every command after newgrp will not be executed. However, it still requires a reboot to take realy effect. For Docker rootless access w/o rebooting does not work.

Comment: This does not work. Running `groups` after running `gpasswd` will __not__ show the newly added group.

Answer (score 1):

```
id webdev
```

seems to be wrong here - you want to know about your own `id`, `takpar`, not `webdev`.

If you compare the outputs of `id` and `id takpar`, you will notice that the former doesn't show the change yet, while the latter shows it. Why? This is because `id` shows the groups of the current process. If you log out and back in, or even only open a new terminal window, you should already see the change without reboot.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake. I've updated that in the question. as you see, the changes can be seen in terminal but it is not applied actually.

Comment: Are you sure that opening a new terminal window the user will see the changes?

Comment: You are right, that doesn't work - probably because the new shell process inherits its groups from its parents. But if you do a complete logout and login again, it should work. If you don't want that, a mere ``ssh localhost` will do for the meantime. Or just `sg`, as Stéphane suggested.