# Can't mount remote file system with sshfs

Tags: filesystems, mount, sshfs, fuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to apply changes of newly added user groups without needing to reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/how-to-apply-changes-of-newly-added-user-groups-without-needing-to-reboot)

I have posted this question in [linux mint users forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=195&t=86084) about some hours ago.

I'm trying to mount a file system with sshfs on linux mint. When I simply try I get

```
fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied
```

Reading [here](http://www.nullamatix.com/fixed-fuse-failed-open-dev-fuse-permission-denied/) I tried ls:

```
yotam@sumsum ~/Documents $ ls -lah /dev/fuse
crw-rw---- 1 root fuse 10, 229 Nov 19 13:00 /dev/fuse
```

So I tried to add myself to fuse:

```
sudo usermod -a -G fuse yotam
```

But:

```
yotam@sumsum ~/Documents $ groups
yotam sudo
```

I tried the GUI interface of Linux Mint and see there that I'm the only user on the fuse group.
So.... what now?

As a finlal note, I'll say that I can mount the file system with sudo

Edit: After restart I can mount

Comment: If I remember correctly you must re-login after you add yourself to group.

Comment: Possibely. Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the chosen one.