# Incompatible group permissions in Linux - Is it a bug?

Tags: permissions, users, group, useradd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply changes of newly added user groups without needing to reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/how-to-apply-changes-of-newly-added-user-groups-without-needing-to-reboot)

I am on Ubuntu 11.04. I am creating another user and placing an existing user in the group of other user, hoping to write in the home directory of other user.

```
# uname -a
Linux vini 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC
2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
# whoami
sachin
# su root
# useradd -m -U foo               // create user foo
# usermod -a -G foo sachin      // add user `sachin' to group `foo'
# chmod 770 /home/foo/
# exit
# whoami
sachin
# cd /home/foo/
bash: cd: /home/foo/: Permission denied
# groups sachin
sachin : sachin foo
```

This is totally weird. Though user sachin is in group foo, and group bits for /home/foo/ is set to rwx, sachin can't chdir to /home/foo/. I am not able to understand this.

But, if at the exit step, I switch to sachin user from root, this is what happens:

```
# uname -a
Linux vini 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC
2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
# whoami
sachin
# su root
# useradd -m -U foo               // create user foo
# usermod -a -G foo sachin      // add user `sachin' to group `foo'
# chmod 770 /home/foo/
# su sachin
# whoami
sachin
# cd /home/foo/
# ls
examples.desktop
```

Now, whatever is happening here is totally incomprehensible. Does su sachin inherits some permissions from the root user at this step?

A solution that was suggested was to use `newgrp`, which updates the group and other user information. So if I do `newgrp - sachin`, then I get access to the directory of the newly created user, but if I create one more user and follow the same steps `sachin` does not get access to the latest users directory.

This behavior is indeed very baffling.

Any explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to logout/login/start a new session so that changed groups apply.

Comment: Also, in Ubuntu you really should use `sudo` instead of running as root. Some tools depend upon being run as sudo, not root. And to add users to groups in Debian-derived distros, use the `adduser` wrapper.

Comment: It seems there is no way out other than a re-login at least in my case where I have create a lot of users add myself into their group and access their directories. But I did not expect this kind of dependency

Comment: @dotancohen: Huh? `sudo` runs the given command as root...it is considered bad form to give the root account a password, tough.

Comment: @Bobby: I had a client who insisted running his Ubuntu desktop as root. He had all kinds of problems with things that would seem "corrupted" (Gnome configurations among them I remember, also Chrome font hinting, some other things that I've forgotten). I've learned to never su - in Ubuntu and just to use sudo. And never login to run a desktop as root!

Comment: @dotancohen: I agree that running X/the DE as root is the worst idea you can have. But I think one can assume to be safe as long as you stick to the CLI and especially in such a short command chain. But as I just realized, su needs root to have a password...which is for a sudo optimized system most likely bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current login shell process keeps the group configuration it had before. Especially, compare the output of

```
groups sachin
```

with

```
groups
```

. After logout and login, the difference is gone.

If you cannot relogin due to reasons unclear to me, you have to cascade the `newgrp` stuff. Imnternally, `newgrp` does nothing but "relogging in" in a new layer of processes. If you log out, you have to press Ctrl-D as often as you have newgrp stuff running.

Alternatively, you terminate the inner `newgrp`layer and start another one after a `usermod`. Then you again have access to the current set of groups.

Comment: yes you are right there is a difference between `groups sachin` and `groups` but the issue is that I do not want to do a logout and login. I can't do that because I am running these commands on a server

Comment: If I work on a server, I quite often log out and in again. That doesn't hurt, does it?

Comment: I can't keep logging out and logging in on a server, it is hosting a site for me

Comment: and the hosting requires you to keep logged in? So you have to permanently have your home PC on and SSH program running? Sorry, I really don't get it (but probably it doesn't matter as well)...

Comment: @Sachin: This is the way UNIX works. Group permissions are **only** determined *at login*. You have to log out and log in again.