# Fresh install of Arch, sudo not working for user

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sudo

Pretty barebones Arch installation aside from xcfe4, xorg, and networkmanager.
When using sudo as my default account I receive the prompt "user is not in the sudoers file"

These are my files respectively

**visudo**

```
# User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

**/etc/group**

```
wheel:x:998:andrew
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[andrew@1551-VOSTRO ~]$ sudo pacman -Syu  
[sudo] password for andrew: 
andrew is not in the sudoers file.
```

I am assuming this is something simple, but usually sudo is as simple as installing, uncommenting the wheel group option and adding the user to the group.

Comment: Have you logged out and in again since adding yourself to `wheel`? What's the result of `id` (run as `andrew`)? If the `wheel` group isn't present that's your problem

Comment: You need to reboot/log out and in again, in order for changes to a group to take effect. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/how-to-apply-changes-of-newly-added-user-groups-without-needing-to-reboot

Comment: Logging out was the solution, thank you guys!