# Full access by group user of /var/www/html

Tags: permissions, group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add write permissions for a group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/how-to-add-write-permissions-for-a-group)

On Centos 6 I'm trying to give full access to make and delete by the user `mitch` for `/var/www/http`.

I did `addgroup www` and then `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html` then `groupmod -g www mitch`, and did a `chgrp -R www /var/www/html` but when I went into /html on mitch and tried to make a file with `touch` it said "permission denied."

Can someone help me make anyone in `www` able to create and delete in the html dir?

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root 4096 Feb 13  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Sep 29 23:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Feb 13  2012 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Oct  1 21:23 error
drwsrwsr-x.  2 root www  4096 Oct  2 16:15 html
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Oct  2 16:13 icons
```

is the ls -la output for the /var/www dir

Comment: `/var/www/html` and `/html` are not the same. Either there you have your answer, or you should correct your post.

Comment: Another idea is that you must logout and log back in for new groups to take affect.

Comment: @Mitchell Ross: Can you show the directory permissions of /var/www/html using `ls -l` and groups in which mitch user is belonging using `groups mitch` command. That will be more easier to debug the problem.

Comment: [mitch@vps html]$ ll
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root www 21 Oct  2 16:15 info.php
and [mitch@vps html]$ groups mitch
mitch : mitch www

Comment: it would be nicer to edit your question and add the results of your `ls -l`. Even better would be to use `ls -al` ;)

Comment: alright there you go Pitt, sorry I'm still kinda new to all this

Comment: Also, it's usually easier to manage permissions in `/var/www/html` through ACLs. See [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12842)

Answer (score 0):

When in the folder /var/www/html check the permissions of the "." 'folder'. 
it could be that mitch does not have the same permissions on that, thus cannot delete/modify stuff in that folder, but since you ran the chmod recursively before, mitch would have 775 permission in all of the subdirectories of /var/www/html.

To fix:

```
cd /var/www/html
chgrp www .
chmod 775 .
```

Comment: Thank you for your guy's help, I just restarted my computer and now its letting me create files under mitch, guess I should have tried a restart before wasting your time, thanks again