# wireshark: Couldn't run /usr/sbin/dumpcap in child process

Tags: permissions, group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add write permissions for a group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/how-to-add-write-permissions-for-a-group)

When I run Wireshark, It shows the following message:

```
Couldn't run /usr/sbin/dumpcap in child process: Permission denied
Are you a member of the 'wireshark' group? Try running
'usermod -a -G wireshark _your_username_' as root.
```

I ran this command: `usermod -a -G wireshark myusername` and checked my groups using `groups myusername` and I was added to the *wireshark* group. But I still get that error message.

```
[nima@nma ~]$ groups nima
nima : nima wheel dialout wireshark
[nima@nma ~]$ ls -l /usr/sbin/dumpcap 
-rwxr-x--- 1 root wireshark 67884 Aug 16 12:04 /usr/sbin/dumpcap
[nima@nma ~]$ /usr/sbin/dumpcap
-bash: /usr/sbin/dumpcap: Permission denied
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update your group IDs by using `newgrp`.

Comment: This is not what you want to do, that would start a new shell with the real group id set to `wireshark`, so every file or process you create for instance would be group-owned "wireshark". You want "newgrp" alone or `sudo -su "$USER"`, and in any case, that would only affect the group list of that new shell process and its children. You'd still need to logout to be able to start a new login session with the new group included.

Answer (score 12):

Did you logout and then login and try the command?