# Permissions not extended to user in minecraft group

Tags: permissions, files, group

I have a directory, under /srv:

`drwxrwxr-x  3 minecraft minecraft 4096 Dec 30 06:23 minecraft`

Owned by user minecraft, group minecraft. Group has read/write/search permissions. I have a user, shelvacu, that is part of the minecraft group:

```
$ groups shelvacu
shelvacu : shelvacu sudo minecraft
```

And, as shelvacu, I run `mkdir /srv/minecraft/testdir`:

```
$ mkdir /srv/minecraft/testdir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/srv/minecraft/testdir’: Permission denied
```

Why? The minecraft group has write permission on the directory, and shelvacu is part of the minecraft group. What am I missing?

Comment: @janos No, in fact that was what I first tried. I can cd just fine, but mkdir gives the same. I just did it slightly differently for clarity, assuming they were the same.

Comment: @janos also, /srv not /src, but thats hardly a problem.

Comment: Did you by any chance just add yourself to the group? This only takes effect when you log in. Use `id` to see your current group memberships. See [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6387)

Comment: @Gilles That was the problem! After logging in again all works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First log in as the user shelvacu.

Then check your groups with `id`, so you don't add shelvacu to a group in one shell but try things inanother, not knowing about the change (as might happen with `groups`).

Change to `/srv/minecraft`, if that doesn't work, then you have not permissions on `/srv` (did make the `/srv/minecraft` as `root` for instance).

Now create directory with `mkdir testdir`. If that doesn't work, check the write permissions on current mount: `mount | grep -F /srv` (if that doesn't give results `/srv` is on `/`)

Comment: It seems I had not known I needed to re-login! Thank you for your help.