# Is group priority available?

Tags: linux, group

`` [tjm@ArchPad bin]$ LANG=en
[tjm@ArchPad bin]$ pwd
/usr/bin
[tjm@ArchPad bin]$ ll | grep wireshark
-rwxr-x--- 1 root wireshark  88K Apr 25 00:22 dumpcap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wireshark 2.0M Apr 25 00:23 wireshark-gtk
[tjm@ArchPad bin]$ groups `whoami`
wheel wireshark users
[tjm@ArchPad bin]$ ``

With command `sudo -G wireshark wireshark-gtk`, I can start wireshark-gtk and listen with out any problems.

But, if I simply run `wireshark-gtk` it says that :

`Could not run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: Permission denied.`

So, it is availible to set a **group priority**, which means that if I (the user) have a group id same as a file, and the file has been set group prority, I will run this file in this group id without `sudo -G`?

By the way, `setgid` is not what I want, for it is not safe and anyone can run this file with group privilege.

Comment: I still could not understand fully: do you want safer or easier solution? Setting file setgid which is executable only by `wireshark` group members looks much easier and does not require `sudo` usage. Try this: `chmod 2710 /usr/bin/dumpcap`. Maybe I just do not understand something.

Comment: 1. Is that supposed to be "sudo -g" (lower-case)? 2. does `newgrp wireshark; wireshark-gtk` allow you to do what you want without sudo?

Comment: I somehow managed to mess with setuid/setgid. Of course `chmod 4710 /usr/bin/dumpcap`. Time to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `id` say?

If you've just now added yourself to the wireshark group, I think you will need to log out and back in again.

(Point found by googling the error message).

Comment: I remember OS X `id` lied to me about _current_ groups, taking information from db instead. OP's question is about Linux, but `id` output maybe not be always portable.

Comment: @siblynx Weird.  I went from the Linux manpage "id - print real and effective user and group IDs". Sounds like OS X is not POSIX compliant, despite being based on existing BSD code.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html

Comment: Yes, exactly as I described. I remember this because I've lost a night trying to figure out why access was still denied. I blindly trusted `id` output without arguments.

Comment: I reboot my Laptop and then it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you will set `/usr/bin/dumpcap` setuid without others but members of `wireshark` group being able to run it, then this setuid setting is safe. Then you just add yourself to `wireshark` group with `usermod -aG wireshark $(whoami)` and you're done.

To setuid it in this way, do `chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap; chmod 4710 /usr/bin/dumpcap`

Btw `sudo` is not suitable for arbitrary permissions manipulation. Consider using modern tools for this purpose, if you still want not to use setuid on file.

Comment: I just consider that if I setgid to dumpcap, anyone can run dumpcap and listen my net interface, which make my computer unsafe.

Comment: How they could run dumpcap if it will be only available to members of `wireshark` group? Or you want to password protect it through sudo?

Comment: Isn't setgid means anyone can run this file with the file's gid? Setgid does not mean only with same group can run this file.

Comment: To successfully enumerate network devices and capture packets, `dumpcap` needs not setgid, but setuid root to work. Also, binary can be setuid/setgid and only runnable by owner/group members of binary, if you will restrict others (`chmod o-rwx`) to run it.

Answer (score 0):

“Group priority” is not a common term. I think you mean the choice of group that is used for filesystem lookups. There is no such thing, or to put it another way, all groups have “group priority”: if a file belongs to a group (but not to your user), and you are in that group, then you get the group permissions, no matter whether the group is your primary group or a supplementary group.

If you are in the `wireshark` group, then you can run `/usr/bin/dumpcap`.

The output of ``groups ```` whoami``` shows that your user account is in the ````wireshark`group, but it doesn't show that your *session* is in the`wireshark`group. To test that, run`groups`with no arguments, or`id`. Group membership is applied when you log in. If you've just added yourself to the group, you need to log out and back in. See [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/i-added-a-user-to-a-group-but-group-permissions-on-files-still-have-no-effect)