# File permissions changed but group user can't write in them

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, permission-denied

I have done the follow:

- chown'd it to a group
- chmod 775
- usermod

this is the status of the permission `drwxrwxr-x  3 root www-data 4096 Mar 22 23:11 html`

The groups my user is in `ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev lxd`

But if I do `touch test` it just gives me a permission denied. Am I missing something.

As for a little background, I'm running a Ubuntu server on AWS. I'm also trying to give my apache user writing permission in the html folder.

Comment: @StephenRauch what do you mean?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yeah, everything is just set to 775, `www-data` group should have full permission

Comment: When you do your `touch test` are you sure the directory is correct? Have you tried a full path?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, whether I do a full path or am directly in the folder, nothing works

Comment: yeah, but I don't want my public html folder to be writable to everyone who accesses it

Comment: Did you reconnect after adding `www-data` to the groups your user belongs to? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6387/203203

Comment: @xhienne that was it