# Can't add self to "sudo" group

Tags: sudo

I recently did a clean install of Linux (the latest version of Debian, version 9.1, 64-bit Cinnamon) and am unable to add myself to the "sudo" group.

When logged in as myself, this is the output of the `groups` command:

```
daniel cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin scanner
```

When I use `su` to become root and enter the command `adduser daniel sudo`, the output is:

```
The user `daniel' is already a member of `sudo'.
```

Sure enough, if I use the command `groups daniel` while still logged in as root (with `su`), the output is:

```
daniel adm cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin scanner
```

(Note that "sudo" is now in the list.)

I have logged out and logged back in several times, but I still am not in the "sudo" group when I run the `groups` command. This means that when I attempt to run a `sudo` command, I get the error:

```
daniel is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Also, I have confirmed that the sudoers file contains an entry granting sudo privileges to the sudo group. When I run `visudo`, these lines are present:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I know that I can use `visudo` to manually add an entry that grants me sudo rights. I mainly want to know why I cannot add myself to the "sudo" group.

Sorry if this is a repeat question. I Googled for a while and couldn't find anyone else who could not add themselves to the sudo group.

Comment: Is there a difference in groups if you log in via TTY instead?

Comment: This was my first time logging in with TTY. I pressed Ctrl-Alt-F1, entered my username and password, and typed `groups`, and the output did include "sudo."

Comment: Possibly related how display manager manages sessions, I've got a hunch your groups would be correct after a reboot (or alternatively killing all sessions using `loginctl`).

Comment: You were right, @sebasth: after rebooting, "sudo" is now in the output of the `groups` command, and I can now use sudo. Thanks! If you want, if you add an answer below, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: I don't know the exact details why this happens to write insightful enough answer. I think its OK if you write down the observation with TTY and rebooting solving issue as your own answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/i-added-a-user-to-a-group-but-group-permissions-on-files-still-have-no-effect)

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate of that question. Prior to asking this question, I saw many posts which stated that logging out would fix the issue. As I stated in the original post, I logged out and back in several times, and that did not fix the issue. I needed to actually restart my computer for the change to take effect.

Comment: @muru This has nothing to do with the other question. The upvotes really raise questions...