# Group membership disappears with tmux

Tags: permissions, tmux, group

I have a weird problem in that my user (on `Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia`) is part of group `docker`, which I verify by starting a terminal:

```
$ groups
me adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

Now, when I fire up tmux, and run the same command, suddenly my `docker` membership disappears:

```
$ tmux
$ groups
me adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

The weird thing is, when I attempt to forcibly add my user to the group `docker` when in tmux, it says I'm already in it!

```
$ sudo adduser me docker
The user `me' is already a member of `docker'.
```

I'm stumped -- why would being in tmux make a difference? For reference, I use `fish` shell and this is my `.tmux.conf`:

```
$ cat ~/config/.tmux.conf 
new-session
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g history-limit 10000
setw -g mode-keys vi
set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/fish
set-option -g default-command /usr/bin/fish
```

**EDIT**

When I restarted my computer, everything worked again (both `tmux` and "normal" shells showed my `docker` membership). I'm still curious -- why did this happen?

Comment: Are you using the same version of `groups` in both shell environments? Have you tried using other commands to show group membership, such as the `getent` or `id` commands?

Comment: Your example shows you creating a new tmux session.  Are you sure you didn't do `tmux attach` instead?

Comment: @AndyDalton I don't think I did `tmux attach`, I just ran `tmux` and it's not aliased to anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673016/in-tmux-i-only-have-2-groups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/i-added-a-user-to-a-group-but-group-permissions-on-files-still-have-no-effect)

Comment: `adduser` just edits a file (the `/etc/groups` file. It does not add a process to a group.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation for this is that the `tmux` session was started before you added your user to the `docker` group. Note that you can log out without terminating an active `tmux` session, but that this session would *not* be affected by changes in group memberships when you re-attach to it after logging in again later.

In your edit to the question you say that when you started a new `tmux` session (after a reboot), the user shows up as member of the `docker` group.  This is expected as you now have a `tmux` session started from an environment where the group memberships had been altered.

Comment: yes try `newgrp` to create a new shell in the new group.

Comment: for me tmux kill-session -t mysession and then tmux new -s mysession and tmux attach -t mysession didn't resolve the problem :(

Comment: @MonaJalal No, because you did not log out before starting a new `tmux` session.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I had to close all existing tmux sessions. After that, all new tmux sessions inherited the correct groups.

Comment: this answer worked for me while https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665147/72728 didn't

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your tmux session file:

```bash
rm /tmp/tmux-1000 # example for uid 1000
```

Then start a new session and see that you are a member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

- Killing the tmux-server and then starting a new session fixed it for me.
- `tmux kill-server`
- `tmux new -s ...`
- Also ensure you exit the current terminal session and start a new terminal after modifying a user/group for the changes to take effect.