# Why is `id` giving different answers for basically the same question

Tags: users, group

I'm on Ubuntu.

```
$ whoami
eugen
$ id
uid=1000(eugen) gid=1000(eugen) groups=1000(eugen),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)
$ id eugen
uid=1000(eugen) gid=1000(eugen) groups=1000(eugen),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),137(docker)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Did you recently add your `eugen` user to the `docker` group without logging out and in again?

Answer (score 3):

I’m guessing you’ve just added yourself to the `docker` group, and haven’t logged back in yet — so `id` shows your old groups (those which the current user has), `id eugen` loads the current groups for `eugen` and includes `docker`.

See [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6387/86440) for details.

Answer (score 3):

`id` alone reports the attribute of the process (its euid, egid, and the supplementary gids), and translates those to corresponding user/group names by querying the `passwd`/`group` databases.

Those ids will have been set in an ancestor process that was running `login` or equivalent and called `init_group()` to retrieve the uid and groups for the user that logged in.

The euid or egid can change if a setuid / setgid application has been executed.

`id eugen` queries the `passwd`/`group` databases. So you see the user and group ids and names that the user would get if they logged in now.

Beside the `setuid`/`segid` application, that can differ if the accounts database has been modified since you logged in.