# Trouble with setting up sudoers file in Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

I keep getting "user is not in the sudoers file" even after I add myself to the sudo group.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you started a new session since adding yourself to the group? See [I added a user to a group, but group permissions on files still have no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/i-added-a-user-to-a-group-but-group-permissions-on-files-still-have-no-effect)

Comment: Okay I will try doing that
Edit: Did that still no luck

Comment: Check if `sudo` group is added to `sudoers` file?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure `id` shows you are in the "sudo" group (logout/login if needed). Also, ensure that there is a directive like `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` in the sudoer config. Also, sometimes distros (or installed features) add "big brother" overrides via the @includedir directive usually at the end of the main sudoers config; retry again after commenting that out (to see if that is the problem ... if so, you may need to add the %sudo line after the @includedir).  Of course, to check/change the config with `visudo`, you'll need to become root or another user with sudo privileges; and to check the effect of changes, use `sudo -l`.

Comment: still didn't work I CONFIRMED that I have in the sudo group and checked the sudoer config file so I just ended up manually adding myself to the sudoers file